# plural form of "a woman doctor": women doctors or woman doctors?

Tags: plural-forms

I have thought that the plural form for "woman doctor" should be "woman doctors" because "woman" seems to be used like an adjective before "doctor."

But the website I rely on says that it's "women doctors." (https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/woman+doctor.html)

Is that true? If so, is only "woman doctor" the special case?

Comment: It's "**doctor(s)**" for a man or a woman. The phrase "woman/en doctors" would be considered sexist or demeaning in the UK. I think it is the same in the US too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I see

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for the information!  But wouldn't there be some situations where you would like to know the sex of the doctors - for example, at the clinic of dermatology? Some clinics indicate the days of week when female doctors are at the clinic in my region.

Comment: For obvious reasons a woman patient might specifically ask for a "woman gynecologist" but otherwise when you enter a hospital there's no way of knowing beforehand the gender, age, ethnicity of a doctor who will be treating you.

Comment: This [Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women+doctors%2C+woman+doctors&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwomen%20doctors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoman%20doctors%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwomen%20doctors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwoman%20doctors%3B%2Cc0) (1960-2019) shows that **women doctors** is the most common form

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I understand.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I think I might use male/female doctor if I really wanted to specify. So I might say (truthfully) that although I do see a GP occasionally I have not seen a male GP for years.

Comment: Mari-Lou is right that "woman/en doctor" is considered sexist if it's unnecessary, So considering this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women+doctors%2Cfemale+doctors&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwomen%20doctors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfemale%20doctors%3B%2Cc0), you might consider "female doctors" to be on the safe side